# Looking to use kill -9 instead of killall

Tags: command-line, kill, killall

Looking to use `kill -9` instead of `killall` using process name.

Is there a way I can `grep` or `awk` the pid of a given process name/s then kill it will `kill -9` ?
`killall` fails a lot for me.

I'm looking to script this for numerous remote machines.
Process name will be one of three.
I want to use something like:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -n $user@$hostname "one liner to use kill -9"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using `pkill`? it can both match a process pattern AND accept a numeric signal value.

Comment: I've read that kill -9 was the most reliable.  Isn't pkill as flakey as killall?

Comment: @PrestonCole what your saying makes not much sense. You can add -9 to killall and pkill as well. A different number just sends another signal to one or more process for all of those tools, and this has nothing to do with flakiness or reliability.

Comment: @Preston Cole You can just write 'kill <process name>'.

Answer (score 7):

The `-9` argument you mentioned specifies the signal `kill` shall send to the process in question. The default is SIGTERM (terminate application), 9 is equivalent to SIGKILL (kill the application immediately and most brutally).

`killall` accepts signal arguments (like `-9` or `-KILL`, I prefer the symbolic names over numbers) too:

```
killall -KILL processname
```

Alternatively, there is `pkill`, which kills processes that match a given command pattern, which accepts signal arguments just as well. You can "preview" what would be killed by it using `pgrep -a`, which lists the matching progresses instead of sending a signal and killing them:

```
pgrep -a processname
pkill processname
```

If you want to match your pattern against the whole command including its arguments and not just the base command, add the `-f` switch:

```
pgrep -a -f something
pkill -f something
```

For more information, check the relevant manual pages: `man kill`, `man killall`, `man pkill` for the various kill commands and `man 7 signal` for an overview of available signals.